# Electron & React-BoilerPlate white screen

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron, react-boilerplate

I have this app that works perfectly fine in Dev mode but not in Production.
My folder structure are (build,dist,node_modules,public,src).

- build
- dist
- node_modules
- public

  - Main.js
  - index.html
- src

  - index.tsx

In my **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.8.0",
  "description": "test welness",
  "author": "Test buddy Inc.",
  "homepage": "./",
  "main": "public/Main.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@aspnet/signalr": "^1.1.4",
    "@craco/craco": "^5.6.2",
    "abp-web-resources": "^5.1.1",
    "antd": "^3.26.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "botframework-webchat": "^4.9.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "craco-antd": "^1.14.1",
    "electron-is-dev": "^1.2.0",
    "famfamfam-flags": "^1.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "mobx": "^5.15.0",
    "mobx-react": "^6.1.4",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.31",
    "query-string": "^6.9.0",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-document-title": "^2.0.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-infinite-scroll-component": "^5.0.4",
    "react-infinite-scroller": "^1.2.4",
    "react-loadable": "^5.5.0",
    "react-moment": "^0.9.7",
    "react-numpad": "^5.1.1",
    "react-onclickout": "^2.0.8",
    "react-player": "^1.15.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "^3.2.0",
    "react-star-ratings": "^2.3.0",
    "react-tiny-link": "^3.3.1",
    "react-youtube": "^7.11.2",
    "recharts": "^1.8.5",
    "universal-cookie": "^4.0.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "electron": "electron .",
    "preelectron-pack": "yarn run build",
    "dist": "electron-builder"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "nonExistentID",
    "win": {
      "target": "nsis" 
    },
    "files": [
      "build/**/*",
      "node_modules/**/*",
      "public/Main.js",
      "package.json"
    ],
    "directories": {
      "buildResources": "assets"
    },
    "extends": null
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/classnames": "^2.2.9",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.23",
    "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
    "@types/moment-timezone": "^0.5.12",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.14",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.13",
    "@types/react-document-title": "^2.0.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.4",
    "@types/react-loadable": "^5.5.2",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.3",
    "@types/recharts": "^1.8.3",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.5",
    "electron": "^9.1.0",
    "react-icons": "^3.10.0",
    "ts-import-plugin": "^1.6.1",
    "typescript": "^3.7.2",
    "electron-builder": "^22.7.0"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

My **public/Main.js**

```
const electron = require('electron');
const app = electron.app;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;
const isDev = require('electron-is-dev');
const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');

let mainWindow;

function createWindow() {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1200, 
        height: 800,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            webSecurity: false
        }
    });
    mainWindow.loadURL(
        isDev
        ? 'http://localhost:3000'
        : `file://${path.join(__dirname, '../build/index.html')}`
    )
    console.log('Let it go', __dirname);
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
    mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
        mainWindow = null
    })
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);

app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit()
    }
});

app.on('activate', function () {
    if (mainWindow === null) {
        createWindow()
    }
});
```

My **src/index.tsx**

```
import './index.css';

import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import * as moment from 'moment';

import App from './App';
import { HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'mobx-react';
import Utils from './utils/utils';
import abpUserConfigurationService from './services/abpUserConfigurationService';
import initializeStores from './stores/storeInitializer';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

declare var abp: any;

Utils.setLocalization();

abpUserConfigurationService.getAll().then(data => {
  Utils.extend(true, abp, data.data.result);
  abp.clock.provider = Utils.getCurrentClockProvider(data.data.result.clock.provider);

  moment.locale(abp.localization.currentLanguage.name);

  if (abp.clock.provider.supportsMultipleTimezone) {
    moment.tz.setDefault(abp.timing.timeZoneInfo.iana.timeZoneId);
  }

  const stores = initializeStores();

  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider {...stores}>
      <HashRouter>
        <App />
      </HashRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
  );

  registerServiceWorker();
});
```

My **public/index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <base href="./" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
  <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="%PUBLIC_URL%/abp.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="%PUBLIC_URL%/signalr.min.js"></script>
  <title>React App</title>
</head>

<body>
  <noscript>
    You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
  </noscript>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

This is in dev mode [image]

And after clicking Ok. It will go back to homepage as what it is supposed to do.[image]

This is the result after it was built. It will display the homepage, but after I click the tenant and click Ok. This is what happened white screen with red E:// in the network tab.
[image]

My progress for this so far is that all the routing is set to "/" and it's not getting the absolute path. It will only get as shown in the image. Is there a possible way to change it to "./" because right now this routing is everwhere in my apps and it's not really good to brute force it to "./" .
This is my **Router component**

```
import * as React from 'react';

import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import ProtectedRoute from './ProtectedRoute';
import utils from '../../utils/utils';

const Router = () => {
  const UserLayout = utils.getRoute('/user').component;
  const AppLayout = utils.getRoute('/').component;

  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/user" render={(props: any) => <UserLayout {...props} />} />
      <ProtectedRoute path="/" render={(props: any) => <AppLayout {...props} exact />} />
    </Switch>
  );
};

export default Router;
```

Comment: any luck on this?

Comment: @MaheshGareja, I run a node server then listen to that port. So that my electron will work. 

mainWindow.loadURL( 'node port')

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an error in `loadUrl()`.  It is looking for a local file on local drive `E:/`, which cannot work in production.

Try:

```
mainWindow.loadURL(
        isDev
        ? 'http://localhost:3000'
        : './index.html'
    )
```

Comment: This won't work though.  Without the path it will just point to ./index.html which is not in my root directory.